# How to return correct value through this function that has a structure array as argument?

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I'm learning `Structures` in C, and trying to write the solution for this problem-

> Create a structure to specify data on students given below: Roll
>   number, Name, Department, Course, Year of joining .
>
> Assume that there are not more than 5 students in the class. (a) Write a function to
>   print names of all students who joined in a particular year. (b) Write
>   a function to print the data of a student whose roll number is given.

My code is given next, with a brief description of various components in the program, and then the source of the problem -

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct student
{
    int roll_no;
    char name[20];
    char department[30];
    char course[20];
    int year_joined;
};

void main()
{
    struct student s[5];
    int i=0,choice;

    printf("\n Enter the following information for each student: \n");
    printf("\n Roll No., Name, Department, Course, Year of Joining\n");
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    scanf("%d %s %s %s %d", &s[i].roll_no, &s[i].name, &s[i].department, &s[i].course, &s[i].year_joined);



    printf("\n Please choose from the following options :\n");
    printf("\n 1. Print names of students who joined in a given year.");
    printf("\n 2. Print data of all students whose roll.no is given.");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1: display_names(s);
                break;
        case 2: student_data(s);
                break;

        default: printf("\n Incorrect choice, please try again.");      
    }


}

void display_names(struct student p[])
{
    int i,count=0;
    int year;
    printf("\n Enter the year you wish to search student info. for : \n");
    scanf("%d",&year);
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        if(p[i].year_joined==year)
        {

    //printf("%d %s %s %s %d", p[i].roll_no, p[i].name, p[i].department, p[i].course, p[i]. year_joined);
    count++;
    printf("\n Student Name: %s\n", p[i].name);
        }

    }
    printf("\n Total Number of students who joined in the year %d is %d\n", year,count);
    if(count==0)
    printf("\n No match found.");
}


void student_data(struct student st[])
{   
    int i,count=0;
    int roll;
    printf("\n Enter roll number of the student: \n");
    scanf("%d",&roll);
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        if(st[i].roll_no=roll)
        {
            count++;
            printf("\n Student Data: Roll No. Name Department Course Year of Joining \n");
            printf("\n %d    %s    %s      %s %d", st[i].roll_no, st[i].name, st[i].department, st[i].course,st[i].year_joined);
            break;


        }
    }

    if(count==0)
    printf("\n No matching Roll Numbers found\n");
}
```

Here's a brief description of this program-

1. Since I'm required to store information about multiple students in the structure, I have created a structure array. The structure `struct student` is defined at the very beginning, and the array is created inside main- `struct student s[5]`
2. The structure is initialized by accepting user input through `scanf()` inside `main()`. There are two `switch` cases for the two functions, asked in the question- `display_names(s) and student_data(s)`
3. The display_names(s) function is called in main, and is defined outside it. The function accepts a `structure array` and asks the user to enter a year. It loops through the initialized array and searches for the input(year of joining) entered by the user. When there's a match, it prints out the names of all students who've joined in that year. Here's a sample output for this function-

*

```
**Enter the following information for each student:
 Roll No., Name, Department, Course, Year of Joining
10 Tim CS MS 2013
20 Shane CS MS 2013
30 John EE ME 2013
40 Mark MECH MS 2013
50 Matt EE ME 2010
 Please choose from the following options :
 1. Print names of students who joined in a given year.
 2. Print data of all students whose roll.no is given.1
 Enter the year you wish to search student info. for :
2013
 Student Name: Tim
 Student Name: Shane
 Student Name: John
 Student Name: Mark
 Total Number of students who joined in the year 2013 is 4**
```

*

This function works fine.

The problem is in the next function `student_data()`. Similar to the first function, it accepts a structure array as input. The way I've designed the function- the idea is to loop through the array until it finds a roll number that's equal to the one entered by the user. When there's a match, it would print out the details of that particular student itself. However, as it stands, this function always prints the first entry in the array, and I can't seem to understand why. I've added the `break` in the `if statement`, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Here's a sample output-

---

```
Enter the following information for each student:
 Roll No., Name, Department, Course, Year of Joining
10 Tim CS MS 2013
20 Shane CS MS 2013
30 John EE ME 2013
40 Mark MECH MS 2013
50 Matt EE ME 2010
 Please choose from the following options :
 1. Print names of students who joined in a given year.
 2. Print data of all students whose roll.no is given.2
 Enter roll number of the student:
40
 Student Data: Roll No. Name Department Course Year of Joining
 40    Tim    CS      MS 2013
```

---

Can you please say where I'm going wrong in this second function?

Comment: `st[i].roll_no=roll` (assignment) should be `st[i].roll_no==roll` (check of equality). Voting to close as a typo. Consider deleting the question before you get an upvoted answer :-)

Comment: Did your compiler whine at you about this ?  It is good practice to turn up the volume on compiler warnings, and think twice (or more) about ignoring them.  Everybody falls into these sorts of traps, regularly -- and a reasonable compiler will be helpful and warn you.

Comment: @gmch No, I didn't get any compiler warnings about the assignment/equality mistake. I thought that's normal of the compiler I'm using(Dev-C++ on Windows 64 bit machine). The only warnings I got were about the `void` definition of the two functions outside `main` when they weren't prototyped inside `main` as `void`.

Comment: OK.  FWIW, for gcc `-Wall` turns on `-Wparentheses` which will warn about this little gem.

Comment: Okay, thanks a ton. Another reason to dump Windows OS for a Mac/Linux machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if statement within student_data() is assigning rather than comparing.

Consider compiling with the -Wall ( or specifically -Wparentheses ) flag:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  int a = 10;
  if ( a = 11 ) printf( "a equals 11\n" );
  return 0;
}
```

Using -Wall:

```
$ gcc main.c -Wall
warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
  if ( a = 11 ) printf( "a equals 11\n" );
$
```